# when running bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd i only get windows.old.000\windows (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

Looking at a friends laptop. 
It started with the `Windows Boot Manager

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
To fix the problem:

1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance.

File: \boot\bcd`

I have gone through and done the DISKPART thing made the partition active then rung 
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
then bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd 
which brings up 
Total identified windows installations:1
[1] D:\windows.old.000\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes No All

I have added it to the list and then I get a user profile error when I log in the next time. Im guessing this is not the right version of windows as there is 3 windows directories on the D drive 
Windows
Windows.old
Windows.old.000
How do I get it to see the Windows and not the old.000 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's corrupted so bad that it's simply not recognizable.  The Windows.old folders are old versions of Windows that were saved during upgrades to newer versions, so they probably won't be much use to you.

Check the drive's health (use a SMART utility), check the file system's health (`chkdsk`).

If they both check out OK, and if a `chkdsk /f` doesn't fix it, then rescue data, remove all partitions so that you have a blank drive, and then install Windows again from scratch (or restore from your last good image backup).